# Creating multi line graphs using Google Charts API

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am attempting to draw multiple lines on a line graph using google charts, using JSON data coming from an API. I am able to draw a single line using the point data from the API, however, am unsure of the data format for multiple lines.

This is my client side code that uses google charts

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "cols": [
            {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
            {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
        ],
        "rows": [
            {"c":[{"v":"Mushroooooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
        ]
    }))

    console.log('done with the sample api 1')
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You successfully retrieved all goals');
    console.log('done with the sample api 2')
});

module.exports = router;
```

The chart I observe is as follows
[image]

However, I am attempting to generate an image that looks like this
[image]

Would somebody be able to help me with the format of JSON data that would generate an image like so, with multiple lines.

Also, is there a way to specify that I'd like to see certain lines dotted and some other solid, in a multi line graph, as below.

PS : I am aware that you could hardcode points as follows, to generate multi lines. However, I'd rather it come from a json object as I show above, so I can replace this with a REST API endpoint that emits a JSON object.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                ['2004',  1000,      400],
                ['2005',  1170,      460],
                ['2006',  660,       1120],
                ['2007',  1030,      540]
            ]);
```

EDIT : Based on @WhiteHat's response below, I have tried to create a chart with 4 lines, two of which are dotted, and two solid. Each of these line would have five points in the chart, for Week 17, Week 18, Week 19, Week 20 and Week 21. However, I see that only two lines get drawn.

This is my json input below

```
res.send({
    "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"}, 

        {"id":"","label":"Solid-Series-1","pattern":"","type":"number"},   
        {"id":"","label":"Solid-Series-2","pattern":"","type":"number"},  
        {"id":"","label":"Dotted-Series-1","pattern":"","type":"number"},   
        {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},
        {"id":"","label":"Dotted-Series-2","pattern":"","type":"number"}, 
        {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Week 17","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null},{"v":5,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Week 18","f":null},{"v":12,"f":null},{"v":11,"f":null},{"v":8,"f":null},{"v":7,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Week 19","f":null},{"v":18,"f":null},{"v":15,"f":null},{"v":12,"f":null},{"v":12,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Week 20","f":null},{"v":24,"f":null},{"v":20,"f":null},{"v":16,"f":null},{"v":14,"f":null},{"v":false}]}
    ]
})
```

**EDIT for adding color**
This is my attempt at specifying color in the JSON input for the chart. However, I am unable to get the color of choice. Kindly advise on how I can specify the color to add.

```
res.send({
         "cols": [
                 {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},

                 {"id":"","label":"Series 1 solid","pattern":"","type":"number"},
                 {"id":"","label":"Series 2 solid","pattern":"","type":"number"},

                 {"id":"","label":"Series 1 dotted","pattern":"","type":"number"},
                 {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},
                 {"id":"","label":"Series 2 dotted","pattern":"","type":"number"},
                 {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},
                 {"id":"","role":"style"}
             ],
             "rows": [
                 {"c":[{"v":"Week 17"},{"v":6},{"v":5},{"v":4},{"v":false},{"v":3},{"v":false},{"color":"red"}]},
                 {"c":[{"v":"Week 18"},{"v":12},{"v":11},{"v":8},{"v":false},{"v":7},{"v":false},{"color":"red"}]},
                 {"c":[{"v":"Week 19"},{"v":18},{"v":15},{"v":12},{"v":false},{"v":12},{"v":false},{"color":"red"}]},
                 {"c":[{"v":"Week 20"},{"v":24},{"v":20},{"v":16},{"v":false},{"v":14},{"v":false},{"color":"red"}]}
             ]
     })
```

Comment: in the edit, there are 7 columns defined, but each row only has 6 values...

Comment: @WhiteHat, it's only now, that I understand what the {"v":false}, refers to. So we pass that in, if it the corresponding column is {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},. I now get it working. However, this JSON syntax is very strict. Is there an easier/cleaner way of getting data from an REST endpoint, and plotting them on the chart w/o having your JSON formatted to such strictness.

Comment: @WhiteHat, also, my apologies for being too inquisitive, but I had one more question here. Is it possible to specify the color for the lines? For example, I'd like my dotted and solid lines for a particular series to be of the same color.

Comment: no problem, just add another column, using a style role, row value can simply be the name of a color, see link in answer...

Comment: @WhiteHat, I have tried to add color based on your response (please see JSON code in edit above). However, I haven't been able to get the color of my choice. If you could kindly take a look at my JSON representation, and advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add multiple lines, add multiple columns to the data table

the data table should have one column for the x-axis,
each additional column will be for the y-axis

```
{
  "cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},  // x-axis
    {"id":"","label":"Slices 1","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 0 - line 1
    {"id":"","label":"Slices 2","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 1 - line 2
    {"id":"","label":"Slices 3","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 2 - line 3
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Mushroooooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":5,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]}
  ]
}
```

you can also add columns for [roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available), such as style or certainty
the role will be applied to the series column it follows

the certainty role will change lines to dotted when the role value is false,
in the following example, the third line will be dotted...

```
{
  "cols": [
    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},  // x-axis
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 0 - line 1
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 1 - line 2
    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 2 - line 3
    {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},             // certainty role - false = dotted
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Mushroooooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":5,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":false}]}
  ]
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},  // x-axis
      {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 0 - line 1
      {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 1 - line 2
      {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 2 - line 3
      {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},             // certainty role - false = dotted
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v":"Mushroooooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":5,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":false}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":3,"f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":false}]}
    ]
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

to add colors, use the `colors` configuration option...

```
  colors: ['cyan', 'magenta', 'lime', 'yellow']
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id":"","label":"x","pattern":"","type":"string"},    // x-axis

      {"id":"","label":"y0","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 0 - line 1

      {"id":"","label":"y1","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 1 - line 2

      {"id":"","label":"y2","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 2 - line 3
      {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},         // certainty role - false = dotted

      {"id":"","label":"y3","pattern":"","type":"number"},   // y-axis - series 3 - line 4
      {"id":"","role":"certainty","type":"boolean"},         // certainty role - false = dotted
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v":"A"}, {"v":3}, {"v":4}, {"v":5},{"v":false}, {"v":6},{"v":false}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"B"}, {"v":4}, {"v":5}, {"v":6},{"v":false}, {"v":7},{"v":false}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"C"}, {"v":3}, {"v":4}, {"v":5},{"v":false}, {"v":6},{"v":false}]}
    ]
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    colors: ['cyan', 'magenta', 'lime', 'yellow']
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. However, in the edit above, as I mention, I was trying to draw out a chart with 4 lines (2 dotted, 2 solid), and see that all lines do not get drawn correctly. Please advise.

Comment: thanks for that. But I notice a couple of inconsistencies in the graph that got generated. 1) The dotted lines do not seem to reflect the color mentioned in code, we intended them to be lime and yellow, they're not. 2) In the legend on the right, the colors are all different from the ones on the actual graph.

Comment: didn't even notice, apparently, you can't use both style and certainty roles -- use `colors` instead, changed last snippet above...

Comment: that's awesome, works. Just a note : Earlier, I was able to specify the size of the graph using the width and height as chart.draw(data, {width: 1000, height: 800}); However, now, upon specifying colors, I'm able to pass in multiple options by creating an options object as follows.
var options = {'title':'My title',
                'width':1000,
                'height':800,
                colors: colorsArray
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);